# Displaying Integer value in a Label , int to String conversion?

Tags: ios, nsstring, stringwithformat

How to display an integer value in a `UILabel` in `ViewDidLoad`? I did for text and date and image but how to convert int to string. I was trying with following code

```
 NSString* label=[aa stringWithFormat:@"%d",((Comments *) [self.list objectAtIndex:0]).noofcomm]]; 
 [self.comments2 setText:label];
```

but didn't work.Please help me.**How to set with the Integer with UILabel?**

This is my comments.h

```
    @interface Comments : NSObject
{
    NSInteger iD;
    UIImage *photo;
    NSString *name;
    NSString *descrp;
    NSDate *date;
    NSString *msg;
    NSInteger noofcomm;
    NSInteger nooflikes;
}
@property(nonatomic,assign)NSInteger iD;
@property(nonatomic,retain)UIImage *photo;
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *name;
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *descrp;
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSDate *date;
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *msg;
@property(nonatomic,assign)NSInteger noofcomm;
@property(nonatomic,assign)NSInteger nooflikes;


@end
```

DBClass.m

```
     #import "DBClass.h"
#import "Comments.h"

@implementation DBClass
- (NSMutableArray *) getMyComments{
    NSMutableArray *wineArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    @try {
        NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        NSString *dbPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath ]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"ComntDB.sqlite"];
        BOOL success = [fileMgr fileExistsAtPath:dbPath];
        if(!success)
        {
            NSLog(@"Cannot locate database file '%@'.", dbPath);
        }
        if(!(sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &db) == SQLITE_OK))
        {
            NSLog(@"An error has occured.");
        }
        const char *sql = "SELECT id, photo,name,descrp, time,msg,comments,likes FROM Com";
        sqlite3_stmt *sqlStatement;
        if(sqlite3_prepare(db, sql, -1, &sqlStatement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
        {
            NSLog(@"Problem with prepare statement");
        }

        //
        while (sqlite3_step(sqlStatement)==SQLITE_ROW) {
            Comments *MyWine = [[Comments alloc]init];

            MyWine.iD = sqlite3_column_int(sqlStatement, 0);

            const char *raw = sqlite3_column_blob(sqlStatement, 1);
            int rawLen = sqlite3_column_bytes(sqlStatement, 1);
            NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:raw length:rawLen];
            MyWine.photo = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
            MyWine.name = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement,2)];

            MyWine.descrp = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement, 3)];

            MyWine.date=[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:sqlite3_column_double(sqlStatement,4)];
             MyWine.msg = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement,5)];
            MyWine.noofcomm = sqlite3_column_int(sqlStatement, 6);
            MyWine.nooflikes = sqlite3_column_int(sqlStatement, 7);

            [wineArray addObject:MyWine];
        }
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"An exception occured: %@", [exception reason]);
    }
    @finally {
        return wineArray;
    }

}

@end
```

RootViewController.m

```
    #import "RootViewController.h"
#import "Comments.h"
#import "DBClass.h"

@interface RootViewController ()

@end

@implementation RootViewController
@synthesize list;
@synthesize image2;
@synthesize name2;
@synthesize descrp2;
@synthesize msg2;
@synthesize date2;
@synthesize comments2;
@synthesize likes2;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    DBClass * mywines =[[DBClass alloc] init];
    self.list = [mywines getMyComments];
    [self.image2 setImage:((Comments *) [self.list objectAtIndex:0]).photo];
    [self.name2 setText:((Comments *) [self.list objectAtIndex:0]).name];

    [self.descrp2 setText:((Comments *) [self.list objectAtIndex:0]).descrp];

    NSDateFormatter* fmtr = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [fmtr setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yy"];
    NSString* label_str = [fmtr stringFromDate:((Comments *) [self.list objectAtIndex:0]).date];  
[self.date2 setText:label_str];
          [self.msg2 setText:((Comments *) [self.list objectAtIndex:0]).msg];
    //[self.comments2 setText:((Comments *) [self.list objectAtIndex:0]).noofcomm];
       // int solution = 1;
//    [self.comments2 setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", solution]];
//    int solution2 = 1;
//    [self.likes2 setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", solution2]];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}
- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [self setImage2:nil];
    [self setName2:nil];
    [self setMsg2:nil];
    [self setDescrp2:nil];
    [self setComments2:nil];
    [self setLikes2:nil];
    [self setDate2:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: Using `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", solution]` is the proper way assuming `solution` is an `int` variable.

Comment: Please post relevant code only.

Comment: @rmaddy An getting data from sqlite database.How to convert int to string.I was tried that one.My question is how to convert and set integer to UILabel.

Comment: Using the `stringWithFormat:` I posted is how you convert an `int` to an `NSString`. Then assign the string to the `text` property of a `UILabel`. If this isn't working then make sure your label variable isn't `nil`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSInteger someInteger = myInteger;
NSString *someString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", someInteger];
myLabel.text = someString;
```

or

```
NSNumber *someNumber = @(myInteger);
NSString *someString = [someNumber stringValue];
myLabel.text = someString;
```

Both will work.

EDIT:

In your case, it will be something like this:

```
NSInteger someInteger = ((Comments *) [self.list objectAtIndex:0]).noofcomm;
NSString someString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", someInteger];
self.comments2.text = someString;
```

If it's still not working, FOR SURE the problem is somewhere else, and not with the conversion. Check with property `noofcomm` has a valid value, check if your label reference is ok (test with a random value before the conversion), and somethings like that.

Comment: Your mentioned someInteger = 20; not this one , Am getting data from sqlite database see DBClass.m , Am asking question about how to set with UIlabel for conversion.How to set with the Integer with UILabel?

Comment: The source of the integer is irrelevant, the conversion will be the same. Just change `myInteger` in the code above by the integer from you sqlite database. The `20` was junst an example

Comment: PLease see my RootViewController.m I was already set with text,image and date but how to set integer once have a look above code.

Comment: edited. As I said, if it doesnt work, the problem is somewhere else

Answer (score 1):

You need to build an NSString

```
int someInteger = 10;
NSString *someString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d", someInteger];
```

Comment: Am getting data from sqlite database here am asking question about how to set with UIlabel for conversion

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like [NSString string_from_int:42] in LCategory since 0.1.3: https://github.com/superarts/LCategory

Answer (score -1):

```
_lbl_yourLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[[dic valueForKey:@"your integer value"] intValue]];
```

On the top left is your label named "yourLabel" , "dic" is your json response dictionary where all the data is coming in key value terms, "your integer value" is the key for which the value will be assign to the label "yourLabel", we have taken intValue because we cannot assign integer value directly to the label.

or you also can try below:

```
int anyInteger = 13;
NSString *yourString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d", anyInteger];
self.yourLabel.text = yourString;
```

Comment: Please use the [edit] link explain how this code works and don't just give the code, as an explanation is more likely to help future readers.